# How to make code runs only once after recursion?

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, break

hourglassSum(arr) method is calling from main method in the beginning. then the method is recursion till the statement gets fail. after recursion, the iteration of sumArray is executed. I thought it will execute only once. but it doesn't work as I expected. How to make it run only once after recursion?

I tried to set flag as local variable.

Run the following code

```
static int rowIncrement=0;
static int columnIncrement=0;
static int[] sumArray = new int[16];
static int count=0;
static void hourglassSum(int[][] arr) {
    int sum=0;
    int size=arr.length/2;
    for(int i=rowIncrement;i<size+rowIncrement;i++) {
        for(int j=columnIncrement;j<size+columnIncrement;j++) {
            sum = sum+arr[i][j];
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    sumArray[count]=sum;
    System.out.println();
    columnIncrement++;
    if(columnIncrement==(arr.length/2)+1) {
        rowIncrement++;
        columnIncrement=0;
    }
    if(rowIncrement<(arr.length/2)+1) {
        count++;
        hourglassSum(arr);
    }
    //doubt : is it execute only once.
    for(int i=0;i<sumArray.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(sumArray[i]+"  ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the input and expected out and the output you are getting

Answer (score 2):

what your code does doesnt explained clearly..
you can add a Boolean Object to the function call and set it to false when finishing the recursion,
see the following:

```
private static void hourglassSum(int[][] arr,Boolean bool) {
    int sum = 0;
    int size = arr.length / 2;
    for (int i = rowIncrement; i < size + rowIncrement; i++) {
        for (int j = columnIncrement; j < size + columnIncrement; j++) {
            sum = sum + arr[i][j];
            System.out.print(arr[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    sumArray[count] = sum;
    System.out.println();
    columnIncrement++;
    if (columnIncrement == (arr.length / 2) + 1) {
        rowIncrement++;
        columnIncrement = 0;
    }
    if (rowIncrement < (arr.length / 2) + 1) {
        count++;
        hourglassSum(arr,bool);
        if(bool){
            bool=false;
            return;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("out");
    //doubt : is it execute only once.
    for (int i = 0; i < sumArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(sumArray[i] + "  ");
    }
}
```

NOTE: call hourglassSum(arr,true)

Answer (score 0):

I think what you might be looking for is a wrapper function. As it currently stands, you have your for loop running inside your recursive method, so every time that method is called it's going to run the for loop. It sounds like you want it to run the recursive method, and then at the end print out the result. To do this, you can put all the recursive code into what's called a helper method, and name it `hourglassSumHelper()` or something like that:

```
private static void hourglassSumHelper(int[][] arr) {
    int sum=0;
    int size=arr.length/2;
    for(int i=rowIncrement;i<size+rowIncrement;i++) {
        for(int j=columnIncrement;j<size+columnIncrement;j++) {
            sum = sum+arr[i][j];
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println(sum);
    sumArray[count]=sum;
    System.out.println();
    columnIncrement++;
    if(columnIncrement==(arr.length/2)+1) {
        rowIncrement++;
        columnIncrement=0;
    }
    if(rowIncrement<(arr.length/2)+1) {
        count++;
        hourglassSumHelper(arr); // Make sure you change the recursive call as well
    }
}
```

Then make `hourglassSum()` a wrapper function whose only purpose is to call the helper method, then print out the result:

```
static void hourglassSum(int[][] arr) {
    hourglassSumHelper(arr);
    for(int i=0;i<sumArray.length;i++) {
        System.out.println(sumArray[i]+"  ");
    }
}
```

Now when you call `hourglassSum()`, it will call the helper method, and then only when it returns from the method will it print out the answer once.